# Using httpRequestXML to request a xml document how would you strip out the information from the xml document using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I need help with running an if and else statement that will retrieve certain amounts of entries using XMLRequest and only return 10 entries instead of 30. I would like some assistance on how to make a function that will get the next set of entries so an example would be get 5 entries the first time and then 2nd click get 10 entries and so on.. I have been stuck and really would like to understand what I am not seeing clearly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>AJAX High Score Example</title>
    <style>
        body {              background-color:   lightgreen; }
        h1 {                color:              black;
                            text-align:         center;}
        button {            display:            block;
                            margin-left:        auto;
                            margin-right:       auto; }
        #box1 {             background-color:   grey;
                            color:              green;
                            border:             2px solid black;
                            width:              550px;
                            padding:            20px;
                            margin-left:        auto;
                            margin-right:       auto;  }
        th, td {            color:              black;
                            min-width:          120px;
                            text-align:         center;
                            border:             1px solid black;}
        table {             margin:             20px auto 0px auto;
                            border:             5px solid black;
                            background-color:   yellow;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Cedrics Music List 1990 XML Part A</h1>
     <div id="box1"></div>
     <button type="button" onclick="getScores()">Display 
     Scores</button>


    <script>
        var request1;
        var ratingValue = new Array();
        var trackValue = new Array();
        var singerValue = new Array();
        var arraySelected = 0;

        function getScores() {
            request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request1.onreadystatechange = callback;
            request1.open("GET", "topSongs1990.xml", true);
            request1.send();
        }

        function callback() {
            if ((request1.readyState == 4) && (request1.status == 
        200)) {
                var parser;
                var xmlDoc;
                var scoreDataXML = request1.responseText;
                console.log(scoreDataXML);
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = 
                parser.parseFromString(scoreDataXML,"text/xml");
                var outputs = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
                console.log(outputs);


                var output = "<table>";
                output += "<tr><th>RATING</th><th>TRACK</th>
                <th>SINGER</th></tr>";


                if (arraySelected > 0; arraySelected < 10; ) {
                ratingValue[i].getElementsByTagName("rating")
               [0].childnodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>"
                + trackValue[i].getElementsByTagName("track")
               [0].childnodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>"
                + singerValue[i].getElementsByTagName("singer")
               [0].childnodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>";
                document.getElementsByTagName("entry").innerHTML;

               }else if (arraySelected > 10; arraySelected > 20; ){


               } else {

                for(i=0; i < outputs.length; i++) {

                    var ratingElement = 
                 outputs[i].getElementsByTagName("rating");
                    var trackElement = 
                 outputs[i].getElementsByTagName("track");
                    var singerElement = 
                 outputs[i].getElementsByTagName("singer");

                    var s1 = ratingElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    var i1 = trackElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    var d1 = singerElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    /*ratingValue[i] = s1;
                    trackValue[i] = i1;
                    singerValue[i] = d1;*/
                    var row = "<tr>";
                    row += "<td>" + s1 + "</td>";
                    row += "<td>" + i1 + "</td>";
                    row += "<td>" + d1 + "</td>";
                    row += "</tr>";
                    output += row;

                }

                /*console.log("The rating Array is " + ratingValue);
                console.log("The initials Array is " + trackValue);
                console.log("The dates Array is " + singerValue); */

                output += "</table>";
                document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = output;

        }
    }


       </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have my function spit out 10 entries per click and if im able to complete that I would like to know how to decrement those values.
(im actually really new to javascript, so I apologize)

I keep getting errors because I cant properly form the right syntax
   ajaxXML6Modified.html:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: getScores is not 
   defined

at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ajaxXML6Modified.html:31)
   onclick @ ajaxXML6Modified.html:31

*Constructive Criticism Welcomed*

Comment: Well your JavaScript has a syntax error so it does not run.   The error should appear in the console when the page loads and clicking on it should point you right to the error.

Comment: my error is a misplaced semi colon on this line but Im confused dont you add a semi colon on a numeral ?   if (arraySelected > 0; arraySelected < 10; ) {